Fill in missing values with 0
I have a SQL query and the resulting table below:
SELECT *
FROM Table A 
WHERE ID = 'A' and task = 'jump'




ID
task
DayofWeek
Hours




A
jump
Monday
3


A
jump
Tuesday
4


A
jump
Wednesday
11



But I want the outcome table to show the remaining days of the week with a 0 for the hours instead:



ID
task
DayofWeek
Hours




A
jump
Monday
3


A
jump
Tuesday
4


A
jump
Wednesday
11


A
jump
Thursday
0


A
jump
Friday
0


A
jump
Saturday
0


A
jump
Sunday
0



I created a temp table, but it only fills in the DayofWeek and hours, but leaves null values for the ID and Task columns.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #dayofweek;
CREATE TEMP TABLE #dayofweek (
    dayofweek VARCHAR (50)
    ,hours INT
);

INSERT INTO #dayofweek (
    dayofweek
    ,hours
)

VALUES 
('sunday',0)
,('monday',0)
,('tuesday',0)
,('wednesday',0)
,('thursday',0)
,('friday',0)
,('saturday',0);




ID
task
DayofWeek
Hours




A
jump
Monday
3


A
jump
Tuesday
4


A
jump
Wednesday
11




Thursday
0




Friday
0




Saturday
0




Sunday
0



How can I complete the table, I have this for situation for various ID and tasks.

I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

The temp table needs to contain the day of week only. All the other values can be obtained with the COALESCE function which returns the first non-NULL argument .
SELECT
    COALESCE(A.ID, 'A'),
    COALESCE(A.task, 'jump'),
    DOW.DayofWeek,
    COALESCE(A.Hours, 0)
FROM
    #dayofweek DOW
    LEFT JOIN Table A
        ON
          DOW.dayofweek = A.DayofWeek AND
          A.ID = 'A' AND A.task = 'jump'

Note that we must include the all the conditions into the JOIN clause for the LEFT OUTER JOIN to work properly, since the condition are applied to the right table.
I also would take care to insert the day of week names with the same case as in the A table. This will yield consistent results and will work independently of case sensitivity.
You should use a parametrized query to support varying conditions, to protect against SQL injection and also to allow the db-server to reuse query plans (assuming SQL-Server):
SELECT
    COALESCE(A.ID, @p1),
    COALESCE(A.task, @p2),
    DOW.DayofWeek,
    COALESCE(A.Hours, 0)
FROM
    #dayofweek DOW
    LEFT JOIN Table A
        ON
          DOW.dayofweek = A.DayofWeek AND
          A.ID = @p1 AND A.task = @p2


@ErgestBasha, using parametrized queries solves this problem.
